# Set natural scroll on mouse integrated with keyboard

Tags: mouse, 22.04, wayland, logitech, mouse-scroll

I have an old Logitech TK820 keyboard with an integrated mouse (which looks like a touchpad).

In addition to the TK820 keyboard/mouse, I have an additional external mouse.

In the Mouse and Touchpad settings, under `Mouse`, I have Natural Scrolling disabled.

This setting works well for the external mouse.

For the integrated mouse on the keyboard, I would like to enable natural scrolling.

Is there a way to detect and set the natural scrolling property for one of the two mice?

---

When I was on 20.04, I would use

```bash
xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech TK820" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

Is there something similar I can do on 22.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew... I was able to find a workaround with the [`solaar`](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) package.

1. First, I enabled `Natural Scrolling` under the Mouse section of *Mouse & Touchpad*
2. Next, in the Unifying Receiver settings for the external mouse, I was able to flip the scroll wheel direction

[image: Solaar Settings for External Mouse]